# How to configure EFCore so it creates a schema (user with no login priviledges)?

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, schema, oracle-sqldeveloper

In my project I am planning to implement multi tenant databases(using finbuckle) , so I need to create databases on runtime based on the tenant configuration. How to achieve this scenario ?

Comment: You'd have a main app, that manages tenants, which would run an SQL that creates user + pwd + database on the oracle server, then assign that connection string to the new tenant.

Comment: Thanks for the reply .I am not familiar with oracle, but in sql server there is no need to provide any external sql or script to create database or user .. it will all be handled as part of migration. Is that possible using oracle ?

Comment: You must be (implicitly via Windows Credentials/explicitly via connection string) sending some credentials to SQL Server to authenticate yourself. You have the hostname for the server, then execute an SQL for each new tenant to create a new user + tablespace, etc. For [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8003.htm#SQLRF01503). For [SqlServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-database-user?view=sql-server-ver15#TsqlProcedure)